# How to change values of cells based on other cell names

Tags: excel

[image: table]

How to change row prices in E column ($ Per GAL), with relation to data in column C?

- If `C = 55` (or [drum](http://oilmiami.com) then `E = value + 0.25` (all other values in row depends on correct value in E column. But changing every other day.
- If `C = 5` gal (or Pail) the `E = value + 0.40`
- IF `C = Bulk` then `E = value + 0.20`

It should be some easy solution. Instead its lots manual work.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Add a column next to E, use a formula with a vlookup table.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just nest some IF statements, like this:

```
=IF(C2="55-Gal Drum",D2/55+0.25,IF(C2="5-Gal Pail",D2/5+0.4,IF(C2="Bulk",E1-0.2,"Need kind")))
```

It is unclear from where price is derived for Bulk. It appears, however, that bulk is always preceded by 5-Gal Pail, and 5-Gal Pail is .20 more than bulk, so in this solution I've merely made the bulk price .20 less than that above. This is not bulletproof - principally because if Bulk is preceded by something other than "5-Gal Pail" the Bulk price would be wrong - but it would appear to work with your data set as presented.

It also was not clear whether the premiums (.20, etc.) for each kind need to change. It seemed these were fixed. If these need to change, I'd likely set up a table in another worksheet to reference in the formula with vlookup.

Comment: Nesting IF statements seems to work for now. Will check vlookup table later. Its a messy table, wasn't done properly from the beginning. Its Time to fix. Recommendations are taking with gratitude!

Comment: Excellent! I thought that might work for you. Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.